# Rigorous proof of time dilation (using only 1 spatial dimension).

Tags: physics, special-relativity

$\newcommand{\set}[1]{\{#1\}}$ $\newcommand{\mc}{\mathcal}$ $\newcommand{\R}{\mathbf R}$ $\newcommand{\ST}{\mathbf S}$

## Introduction

The purpose of this post is to understand the theorem of time dilation in special relativity.
Before even stating the theorem, I wanted to make precise the fundamentals so that one can write a rigorous proof.
Following is my attempt to come up with an axiomatization of special relativity.
I was not able to follow the thought experiments in physics books (though I was able to *appreciate* them).
More precisely, I would not like to use trains and lightning bolts in my arguments since they are not precise mathematical objects.

Also, I have seen a purely mathematical treatment in Gregory Naber's *Geometry of Minkowski Spacetime* but I was not able to follow the motivation behind the postulation of a bilinear form of a certain index on spacetime.
I would like to anchor thing to "speed of light is constant in all inertial frames" and, I believe, the following achieves this.
Basically, I would like to have a "well-motivated" development of the subject.
Of course, this is inherently a subjective matter.
([Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2861311/rigorous-formulation-of-special-relativity) is my previous attempt at formalizing special relativity).

The problem I am facing is mentioned in the last section.
Briefly, I am stuck at proving time dilation without having at least two spatial dimensions.
Further, the axiom that I right now can come up with to exploit the extra dimension is ugly.
More details below.

I have not given the proofs of any of the theorems below for two reasons.
One is that this post is already very long and the second is that the proofs of these theorems are routine given the definitions.

Lastly, I hope the motivations of the axioms and definitions are clear to the reader and I will make every effort to clarify any of them if needed.

## Axiomatization

We postulate that **spacetime** is a $2$-dimensional oriented affine space, which we denote as $\ST$, and whose elements are called **events**, equipped with a collection $\mc P$ of $1$-dimensional affine subspaces, whose elements are called **photons**.

A **particle** is any $1$-dimensional affine subspace of $\ST$.
Thus each photon is a particle.

> **Axiom 1.**
> There exist at least two non-parallel photons.

A **frame of reference** is an orientation preserving affine isomorphism $T:\R^2\to \ST$.
The idea is that any frame of reference assigns coordinates to spacetime.
We think of the $x$-axis of $\R^2$ as the "spatial axis" and the $y$-axis as the "temporal axis."
More formally, given a frame of reference $T:\R^2\to \ST$ and an event $p$ in $\ST$, we define the **spatial coordinate** of $p$ as measured by $T$ as the $x$-coordinate of $T^{-1}(p)$, and the **temporal coordinate** of $p$ as measured by $T$ as the $y$-coordinate of $T^{-1}(p)$.
The **observer** corresponding to $T$ is defined as the image of the $y$-axis under $T$.
The idea here is that the events to which $T$ assigns $0$ as the spatial coordinate are the ones "experienced by $T$."

Let $T$ be a frame of reference.
We say that two events $p$ and $q$, we say that $p$ and $q$ are **simultaneous** with respect to to $T$ if $p$ and $q$ have the same temporal coordinates with respect to $T$.
Let $\alpha$ be a particle.
The **velocity** of $\alpha$ as measured by $T$ is defined as the slope of the line $T^{-1}(\alpha)$.
The magnitude of velocity is called **speed**.

A frame of reference $T$ is said to be **admissible** if each photon has speed $1$ with respect to it.

> **Axiom 2.**
> There exists an admissible frame of reference.

> **Axiom 3.**
> If a particle has speed $1$ with respect to an admissible frame of reference then the particle is a photon.

> **Theorem 1.**
> Let $\alpha$ and $\beta$ be two photons which are not parallel.
> Then every particle parallel to $\alpha$ or $\beta$ is a photon, and every photon is parallel to $\alpha$ or $\beta$.
> Further, through every event there pass exactly two photons.

Now let $S$ and $T$ be two admissible frames of references and assume that $T(0) = S(0) = p$ for simplicity of the discussion.
Let $v_1 = T^{-1}(Se_1)$ and $v_2 = T^{-1}(Se_2)$.
Let $\ell_i$ be the line passing through the origin and $v_i$.
If $m_1$ and $m_2$ be the two photons passing through $p$ and let $r_i = T^{-1}(m_i)$.
Since each photon has speed $1$ with respect to $T$, we have
$$
r_1 = \set{(x, y)\in \R^2:\ x=y} \quad \text{ and }\quad r_2 = \set{(x, y)\in \R^2:\ x+y=0}
$$
Now using the fact that each photon has speed $1$ with respect to $S$, and he fact that both $S$ and $T$ are orientation preserving, we see that $r_1$ passes through $v_1+v_2$ and $r_2$ passes through $v_1-v_2$.
From this it follows that the angle which $v_1$ makes with the $x$-axis is same as the angle which $v_2$ makes with the $y$-axis.
(The following lemma is not exactly true, for in the figure followed by the lemma we could very well replace $v_1$ by $-v_1$ and $v_2$ by $-v_2$. I still think it is true enough and hence I do not remove it.)

> **Lemma 2.**
> Let $S$ and $T$ be two admissible frames.
> Write $v_i = T^{-1}(Se_i)$ for $i=1, 2$.
> Let $l_i = \set{tv_i:\ t\in \R}$, $m_1$ denote the $x$-axis, and $m_2$ denote the $y$-axis.

- The orientation of $(v_1, v_2)$ is same as the orientation of $(e_1, e_2)$.
- The line joining $v_1$ and $v_2$ is parallel to $\set{(x, y)\in \R^2:\ x+y=0}$, and the line joining the origin and $v_1+v_2$ is parallel to $\set{(x, y)\in \R^2:\ x=y}$.
- The length of the two vectors $v_1$ and $v_2$ are equal.
- The signed angles $\angle(m_1, l_1)$ and $\angle(m_2, l_2)$ are equal.

[image]

Given two frames $S$ and $T$, we define the **velocity** of $S$ with respect to $T$ as the velocity of the observer corresponding to $S$ with respect to $T$.

> **Theorem 3.**
> Let $S$ and $T$ be two admissible frames.
> Then the velocity of $S$ with respect to $T$ is same as the negative of the velocity of $T$ with respect to $S$.

## Question

Now suppose $S$ and $T$ are two admissible frames with $S$ having speed $v$ with respect to $T$.
It is immediately clear that if $p$ and $q$ are two events that are observed to occur in the same place by $T$, then the temporal difference between $p$ and $q$ is measured differently in the two frames.
We would like to quantify this difference.
The problem then essentially asks to find out the length of $v_2$ (or $v_1$) in the figure above, since the dilation factor is nothing but $XO/BO$.
However, the axioms so far cannot be used to derive the length of $v_2$.

In Einstein's thought experiment we have a train housing a light clock which fires a photon perpendicular to the motion of the train and it is tacitly assumed that the dimension perpendicular to the motion of the train `behave the same with respect to both the observes.'
I am able to make this thought experiment precise but with a very ugly axiom (that directions perpendicular to relative motion are unaffected).
Also, it is unsettling that one needs an extra spatial dimension to establish this factor of time dilation.

EDIT: Andreas Blass had pointed out in the comments that the temporal order of two events may be different for different observers. This amounted to an error in my formalism and resulted in this edit.

Comment: Every text I read when I studied special relativity in college derived time dilation in *one* spatial dimension, as that is all that is needed.  One traveler goes out (along a line), then comes back.  John Wheeler's (old) ***Spacetime*** explains it perfectly.

Comment: I'm confused because, on the one hand, you say you're trying to axiomatize special relativity and, on the other hand, you introduce $\tau$ "to ensure that the temporal order of any two events is independent of the observer", which contradicts special relativity.  The temporal order of space-like separated events depends on the observer in special relativity.

Comment: @AndreasBlass I do not know special relativity well (the point of this post is to learn it). I somehow thought that temporal order remains preserved across reference frames. Give me some time to edit. I will chuck that part. This raises a small problem later but that's alright.

Comment: @AndreasBlass Meanwhile, if you have time, can you go over the axioms and see if they are alright and capture special relativity correctly, of if more axioms need to be added.

Comment: could you explain why you think the postulation of the bilinear form is unnatural? TO me that's a very natural thing to do provided we wish to impose the constancy of $c$ in all "inertial"(whatever that means) coordinate systems. Because we're considering a curve $\gamma$ (the path of light) in spacetime and upon the introduction of a coordinate system $\phi(\cdot)=(t(\cdot),x(\cdot),y(\cdot),z(\cdot))$, the requirement that its speed be equal to $c$ is equivalent to the requirement that the tangent vector $\gamma'$ annihilate the bilinear form $-c^2dt^2+dx^2+dy^2+dz^2$.

Comment: Next, if we wish to look at another "intertial" coordinate system $(\tau,\xi,\eta,\zeta)$, then the requirement that $\gamma$ again have speed $c$ relative to to this coordinate system is that the tangent vector $\gamma'$ (pointwise) annihilates $-c^2d\tau^2+d\xi^2+d\eta^2+d\zeta^2$. So, if we want to make an intrinsic definition out of all of this, we had better consider a Lorentzian metric tensor $g$ with signature $(-,+,+,+)$. With this we can then define an inertial coordinate system to be one for which $g$ takes the form $g=-c^2dt^2+dx^2+dy^2+dz^2$.

Comment: By doing so, we will have encoded one of our physical axioms into a proper geometric framework. The reason I raise this comment is that (as mentioned by Lee Mosher in your previous post), you're completely avoiding the theory of bilinear forms which is what special relativity is about (in fact a lot of special and general relativity is about understanding in detail the causal structures of the metric tensor).

Comment: @AndreasBlass Thanks. I was making a silly mistake. I clearly do not want the temporal order thing.

Comment: @peek-a-boo Thank you for your comments. You explanation of the purpose of the bilinear form is helpful. However, since I seem to have made progress with my "low-tech" approach I would like to see it go through in full.

Comment: ok that's fair enough, though it's been a while since I've done special relativity so I'm not sure I'll be able to give you a satisfactory answer. BTW there's a small issue missing in my previous comment: what I've said amounts to the constancy of speed of light being encoded into the "kernel" of a quadratic form. Now, it is a standard linear algebra fact that any two quadratic forms (of same signature) with the same zero set must be related by a scalar multiple. That's why I was able to make the leap in going from two coordinate systems and combining everything into a single metric tensor.

Comment: @peek-a-boo Thanks for more clarification. As for my formalism, I am a bit biased, but I think it should make sense to the untrained person too, as long as they are willing to accept that the speed of light is same in all inertial frames. Since you already know about relativity from before, I think it would take very little time for you to go through my write up.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork I have access to Wheeler and Taylor's *Spacetime Physics* (Second Edition). Is this is the book you had mentioned? I am unable to find the explanation that you hinted at. Can you please tell me which chapter I can find it in? Thank you.

Comment: I studied out of that book decades ago, and don't have it at hand.  Just look up "Grandfather paradox" in the index.  Everything is one-space-dimensional.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork I looked at the index and couldn't find grandfather paradox. I also did a C+F and typed 'grandfather' and got no hits. Perhaps you are talking about a different book.

Comment: Is it possible that we may be able to clarify the thought experiments from physics books? Your way seems much more difficult. That would be okay if you understood the physical arguments and wanted a more formal approach, but it seems like you are trying to use formalism to understand something that is intuitive.

Comment: @JohnDouma Yes. All I am trying to do is formalize the though experiments. So if a thought experiment that uses only 1 spatial dimension can be put in an answer then that would definitely help. (I personally find the thought experiments ambiguous. This is my attempt to understand the thought experiments.)

Comment: The problem with not using a perpendicular dimension to derive the time dilation is that in one dimension you have two things that vary. You have a length contraction as well as a time dilation. Einstein used the perpendicular direction because the measurement from each observer to the mirror is the proper length, meaning the endpoints where you place the ruler are at rest for each observer. That, along with the postulate that they measure the speed of light to be equal is what allows us to derive the time dilation.

Comment: @JohnDouma That is exactly my concern. I can't see any way to derive time dilation without using an extra spatial dimension (I made this noise towards the end of my post).

Comment: Do you understand that from each observers point of view, the mirror is neither moving toward or away from them so that the distance is the same? Also, since each observer measures the speed of light to be constant they agree that the total elapsed time must be split equally into the time it takes for light to get to the mirror and the time for it to return? If so, that justifies the isosceles triangle with a height of $L$ and the rest is just algebra.

Comment: @JohnDouma I do not see how it *follows* that the perpendicular direction does not measure different in the two frames. One has to demand that somehow by placing an appropriate axiom. That can be done. But my query is simply if 1-spatial dimension suffices. David Stork mentioned that it does.

Comment: Imagine that the two observers start at rest at the same position. They measure the distance as $L$. One of the observers agrees to move off in one direction and accelerate to a constant speed toward the other. During that entire time, the observer that moved away and back, observes that the mirror is not moving toward or away. That's why they measure the same distance.

Comment: Try "Twin paradox."  Also, this belongs on Physics.SE.